# Understanding UTF-8 encoding in emails

Tags: email, content-type, unicode-string, thunderbird

I am trying to understand hoUTF-8 encoding in emails works. I thought looking at what Thunderbird does should help. So I wrote a email with the characters "äöü" and then looked at the source in Thunderbirds "Sent"-Folder.
The mail-header says

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Those characters are shown as "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼" (Unicode-Positions 195 164 195 182 195 188). I then followed the rules (that I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples)) and was able to get back my original letters. Using 195 164 as an example: bytes are `1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 * 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0`. The first two bits indicate I need to process those two bytes. I then drop the 4 leading bits from the the first bytes and the 2 leading bits from the 2nd bytes which gives my `0011100100` or 228 - unicode-position of "ä".

BUT then I extended that string to "`äöüÄÖÜ`" and saw "`Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã„Ã–ÃœÃŸ`" which I find in unicode at positions `195 164 195 182 195 188 195 8222 195 8211 195 339 195 376`. Eh...8222, 8211, 339, 376??? All values > 255 - I thought 8bit-encoding could't go beyond 255?

How can I decode that text correctly?

Comment: It's not about utf-8, a *byte* cannot go beyond 255 by definition. If you have 8222, you either red multiple bytes or did something else entirely. Instead of `195 8222` you should have seen `195 132` and then `195 150` instead of `195 8211`.

Comment: The 8222 is unicode-position of "„" which is part of the source of that mail-msg as Thunderbird showed it. I'm puzzled to see that in a mail which has `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`.

Comment: The characters you see in whatever tool you are using to view this message are irrelevant. There isn't unicode character `„`, even though it may appear that way if you interpret the data *in some way*. Your message is a stream of bytes, not a stream of unicode codepoints. When you view it as such I'm sure you will see it is correct.

Comment: Ultimately, when viewing it with a proper mail-viewer, the msg is correct - and I'm not arguing that. I have a problem understand the message-transfer: I think I had understood UTF-8 encoding after I was able to decode "Ã¤" as "ä". But that model didn't work for "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã„Ã–ÃœÃŸ" and I'm asking "Why? " ;)

Comment: `'Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã„Ã–ÃœÃŸ'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')` in Python gives `'äöüÄÖÜß'` so it's a flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Read https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html

Comment: Like I said, you are not decoding *characters to characters*. You are decoding *bytes to characters*. Any "characters" that your tool shows you when you show it raw data are completely bogus. To do the decoding manually, you need to grab a hex viewer (or a decimal viewer) that shows you the data as a sequence of *numbers*, 0-255 each.

Comment: I see - my bad :(    Thanks!